# What is the difference between pandas.Timeseries and pandas.Series

Tags: python, pandas

My code is breaking at the following assert:

```
assert(type(series_one) == pandas.TimeSeries)
```

It seems the type I pass it is a 'pandas.core.series.Series', but the index of said series is 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: your question makes little sense, you're asking about determining whether something is a timeseries or a series and then ask why the index is a datetimeindex, why should this be a surprise?

Answer (score 0):

There are two confusing points here. First, a `pandas.Series` has an **index**, and it has **values**. The index may have varying types like `CategoricalIndex`, `MultiIndex`, `TimeDeltaIndex` and your `DatetimeIndex`.

Second, in your assertion, you type check the entire series, not the index. Moreover, it is recommended to use `isinstance` for type checking, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python) for more:

```
assert(isinstance(series_one, pandas.Series))
```

To check for a series, you used `pandas.TimeSeries` but this is depreciated and should be replaced with `pandas.Series`:

```
# creating pandas.TimeSeries
dummy = pd.TimeSeries([1,2,3])
FutureWarning: TimeSeries is deprecated. Please use Series
```

A future warning is printed automatically indicating that `TimeSeries` should not be used in future.

To sum up, get your head around what you want to check in your assertion, either the entire Series or the index of the Series. In case you want to check for a Series, then use `pandas.Series` instead of TimeSeries.